# Вернуть реализующийся интерфейс IEnumerable<T> через метод, C#

Tags: c#, ссылки, интерфейс, методы

Добрый день, очень сильно плаваю в теме про обобщенные интерфейсы, методы. Был бы весьма благодарен за подсказку, либо за ссылки, в каком направлении следует копать, читать. Теорию прочитал с сайта professorweb.ru про интерфейсы, обобщение. Теория теорией, что то понял, чего то нет, но на практике все равно не могу реализовать следующую задачку.

К примеру, имеется код:

```
DataPerson dataPerson;
IEnumerable<Person> person = dataPerson.<IEnumerable<Person>>Get(); 
// как я понял, метод Get() должен в person записать значение ссылочного типа 
// на реализующий интерфейс типа Person? Не представляю как реализовать это.
// В плане непонятны мне следующие вопросы: 

// 1. Где следует реализовать этот интерфейс? 

// 2. Не понимаю про двойное обобщение вида <T<V>>,
// а именно каким образом это указать в методе Get()?

// 3. Не понимаю как вернуть интерфейс через метод.
```

Класс Person:

```
class Person 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string fName, string lName)
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
    }
}
```

Класс DataPerson:

```
class DataPerson
{
    // как я примерно представляю объявление функции Get()
    public IEnumerable Get<T,V>() 
        where T : IEnumerable<V> 
    {
        // как реализовать, к сожалению не представляю
    }   
}
```

Как собственно реализовать метод Get() в классе DataPerson?

Comment: Реализация явно будет зависеть от того, из чего именно вы достаете данные. Откуда DataPerson должен достать список? из базы? из текстового файла? стянуть с вебвсервиса. (хотя лично мне кажется что это какой-то овердизайн ради овердизайна). как он должен создавать новые объекты, не зная ничего об их конкретном типе?

Comment: В реальной задаче используется библиотека System.Linq, и класс DataContext, а экземпляр объявляется вида DataContext dataContext = new StorageDataContext(); где StorageDataContext класс который должен реализовать метод Get();

Comment: Так добавьте это в вопрос. пока непонятно, в чем именно у вас затруднения - собственно, вернуть IEnumerable, зная как создавать объекты? если да - то это достаточно легко сделать :)

Comment: а вот полноценно привязать это к базе - это вопрос уровня "как мне написать свой ORM". и ответ на него достаточно обширный. может быть вам стоит в сторону EF посмотреть?

Comment: @PashaPash , _"в чем именно у вас затруднения - собственно, вернуть IEnumerable, зная как создавать объекты?"_ Да, здесь затруднение, можно поподробней пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш метод скорее всего должен быть объявлен как

```
class DataPerson
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
        where T : new()
    {

    }
}
```

т.к. реально у него всего один тип-параметр - тип выбираемых объектов.

и использоваться как

```
IEnumerable<Person> person = dataPerson<Person>Get();
```

Реализовать его можно двумя способами:

Действительно создать что-то, что реализует интерфейс IEnumerable. Например, массив или список. Заполнить его и вернуть из метода:

```
class DataPerson
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
        where T : new()
    {
        var query = buildSomeQueryFor(typeof(T)); // построить запрос для выбора объектов типа T
        DataRow[] dataRows = selectSomeRowsFromDB(query); //

        var result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in dataRows)
        {
            result.Add(MapDataRowTo<T>(row));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private MapDataRowTo<T>(DataRow row)
        where T : new ()
    {
        var newObject = new T();
        // map values from row to newObject

        // return
        return newObject;
    }
}
```

Второй способо - использовать ключевое слово `yield`:

```
class DataPerson
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
        where T : new()
    {
        var query = buildSomeQueryFor(typeof(T)); // построить запрос для выбора объектов типа T
        DataRow[] dataRows = selectSomeRowsFromDB(query); //

        foreach (var row in dataRows)
        {
            yield return MapDataRowTo<T>(row);
        }
    }

    private MapDataRowTo<T>(DataRow row)
        where T : new ()
    {
        var newObject = new T();
        // map values from row to newObject

        // return
        return newObject;
    }
}
```

Использование yield завернет ваш метов в обертку-IEnumerable, которая будет возвращать элементы по мере обращения к ним из вызывающего кода. Т.е. выполнение метода `Get<T>` будет происходить кусками, от одного вызова yield к следующему. В MSDN есть достаточно подробная [документация по этой фиче языка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Comment: Большое спасибо, с вашей помощью уже не так сильно плаваю в этой теме..

Comment: @PashaPash скажите пожалуйста, а какой смысл в таком определении `class DataPerson { public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>() where T : new()  { } }`?
По идее из имени класса следует, что метод DataPerson.Get создает объекты типа Person. Т.е. Get<T>() надо заменить на Get() и убрать where T : new(). Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Stack честно - не знаю. это не мое определение :). топикастер хотел версию с генериками - я оставил генерики, максимально ее упростив. в целом - да, генерики там не нужны.

Comment: @Stack мой ответ скорее про yield, чем про генерики

Comment: @PashaPash если "генерики там не нужны", то наверное лучше изменить ответ в части "метод скорее всего должен быть объявлен как ...".

Comment: @Stack тогда пришлось бы изменить и вопрос - ведь там ТС явно запутался с генериками (с ограничениями на них), и я пытался косвенно это решить

Answer (score 4):

> Как собственно реализовать метод Get() в классе DataPerson?

```
class DataPerson {
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get() {
        return new List<Person>() {
            new Person(),
            new Person()
        };
    }
    // или так
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get() {
        return new[] { new Person(), new Person() };
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, и с вашей помощью тоже внес кое какие изменения и теперь ситуация стала более прозрачной. :)